# How do I determine the version of Hyperledger Fabric code within the Docker images?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Received this question on the making list:

Where can I find information about which version of the code is running on each docker image?

Answer (score 3):

the tags for the published Docker images correspond to Fabric version inside the image.
So hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.1.1 corresponds to Fabric v1.1.1 (for the x86_64 platform).  Starting with v1.1, we also publish multi-architecture images which simply use the Fabric version as the tag.

If the images you've downloaded have been re-tagged as **latest**, you can use the `version` command associated with each of the executables:

```
docker run --rm hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest peer version

docker run --rm hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest orderer version

docker run --rm hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest fabric-ca-server version
```

(you can replace the **:latest** tag with whichever tags you have)